# Converting a varchar date to date datatype in mssql

Tags: sql-server, datetime

My column is storing value as 201909(i.e September 2019), I need to convert it to format 2019-09-01 and store in it another column in a MSSQL .Please help

Comment: What have you tried? As a hint, a date contains both a year, month and day; yours has just a year and month. I also suggest you store your value as a `date`. Date/time data types don't have formatting, they are stored as binary values. If you need to display a specific format, control that in your presentation layer.

Comment: Try `CAST(YourYYYYMMColumn + '01' AS date)`.

Comment: Or  `DATEFROMPARTS(left(YourYYMMColumn,4),substring(YourYYMMColumn,5,2),1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a statinc '01' string with your current string and then try to convert as below-

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(20)
SET @D = '201909'

SELECT CAST(@D+'01' AS DATE)
```

Output is-

```
2019-09-01
```